# can someone help me make this Python code less ugly? Finding Facebook Friends on app, and not on app

Tags: python, django, facebook, dictionary

```
DEFAULT_CONNECTION_LEVEL = 10
# Up to a whole day
UPDATE_FRIENDS_EVERY_N_MINUTES = 360


def find_friends_on_app(friends):
    """
    Checks each facebook id to find which facebook friends
    use our app
    """
    facebook_ids = [friend["id"] for friend in friends]
    dt_friends = User.objects.filter(
        facebook_id__in=facebook_ids)
    friends_on_app = {friend.id: DEFAULT_CONNECTION_LEVEL for friend in
                  dt_friends}
    fb_id_on_app = {friend.facebook_id: "value" for friend in
                dt_friends}
    friends_not_on_app = \
        [{'Name': friend.get("name"),
          'id': friend.get("id")} for friend in friends if
         fb_id_on_app.get(friend.get("id")) is None]
    return friends_not_on_app, friends_on_app
```

The Code gets all of a user's Facebook friends who use our app and returns a dictionary with keys that are their id's in our database and values that are a default connection level.

The code should also return all of the users Facebook friends who aren't using our app.

I made fb_id_on_app a dictionary of keys that are facebook_id's so that I could take advantage of the O(1) lookup time for dictionaries. If I had made it a list it would have been an O(n) where n is the size of the list to check if the value was in there.

I'm sure there is a better way to do this any ideas? We are using django framework as well.

Comment: This might be a better question for http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Offhand I can see only minor improvements (esp. in formatting:-):

```
def find_friends_on_app(friends):
    friend_ids = User.objects.filter(facebook_id__in=[friend["id"] for friend in friends])
    friends_on_app = {friend.id: DEFAULT_CONNECTION_LEVEL for friend in friend_ids}
    fb_id_on_app = set(f.facebook_id for f in friend_ids)
    friends_not_on_app = [{'Name': friend.get("name"), 'id': friend.get("id")}
                          for friend in friends if friend.get('id') not in fb_id_on_app]
    return friends_not_on_app, friends_on_app
```

Really, the ugliness depends on the heavy over-use of the words "friend" and "id" and variants thereof -- which makes it hard to tell what's a `friendxyz` at each step and what's the difference between its `['id']`, its '.id', its '.facebook_id'... and I can't fix that ugliness without the deeper understanding of the intended semantics which that overuse masks from me!-)

Comment: hey Thanks I made your changes. I liked that you used sets I didnt realize they were dictionaries with dummy values, which was essentially what I had done before. The formattings a little weird because of Pep8.

Comment: Yep, when I implemented the first version of `set`, over a decade ago, it was exactly built on top of `dict` -- nowadays it's optimized C code, not just more readable (when appropriate) than a `dict`, but also saving some memory.  BTW I'm not aware that I'm violating PEP 8 anywhere here...?